# android studio showing me continuously pushing while uploading it on github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

[This massages is showing and nothing happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlb00.jpg)

Git was configure correctly with android studio , Project was pushing successfully but I add someone as contributor in git project and then this is happening with me and contributor as well ,
It uninstall git and reinstall git but this is not working ,
And I made a new project and new repository and try to push project , but now same issue is coming.
I don't know what to do ,

Comment: I suppose there is something wrong with the remote configuration in git settings. Could you try the same from Github for desktop or maybe the command line?

Comment: I try it from different laptop ,

Comment: Same thing here, "Pushing..."